# Combine MPEG-DASH segments (ex, init.mp4 + segments.m4s) back to a full source.mp4?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mpeg-dash

GPAC, http://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/, can be used to do video segmentation along with MPEG-DASH spec. One type of results is a combination of init files (ex, init.mp4) and several roughly fixed-duration segments (ex, segment-%d.m4s). What if I just got those results and I like to reverse/combine them back to one full source.mp4 file? Can I use GPAC or ffmpeg for this?

Comment: KSV HDS downloader is similar, I would ask him http://stream-recorder.com/forum/adobe-hds-downloader-t14823.html

Comment: @StevenPenny Do you mean HDS fragments are similar to ones defined in DASH-AVC/264?!

Comment: The concept is similar. Beyond that I dont know.

Comment: can someone answer this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55701262/combine-specific-mpeg-dash-segments-ex-int-mp4-seg-1-m4s-seg-3-m4s-into-one

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can just use the `cat` command or similar tools to do this job:

```
cat init.mp4 > source.mp4
cat segment-1.m4s >> source.mp4
cat segment-2.m4s >> source.mp4
...
```

To do this automatically for all segments in the current folder, the following command can be used:

`cat init.mp4 $(ls -vx segment-*.m4s) > source.mp4`

The -v parameter for `ls` sorts the output naturally (i.e. 1, 2, ..., 10, ..., 100), otherwise it sorts lexically (i.e. 1, 10, 100, 2, ...).
The -x parameter puts the output on a line instead of columns.

Comment: The concatenated file won't be the same to the original file though.

Comment: Could you also explain How to do in windows ? I tried type command but it did not work. type segment-1.m4s segment-2.m4s > final.mp4 this command executed successfully, it created the mp4 file as well but when I run it then it is not running saying file corrupted or not supported error.

Comment: I've also found that the `cat` implementation of Windows does not work as expected for this. I ended up using a Linux machine or the `cat` version provided by Cygwin (https://www.cygwin.com/)

Comment: @DrakeGuan _"concatenated file won't be the same to the original file"_   
Why?

Comment: @3dGrabber, wow this is a 5-year-old question! I'd say Daniel is right for the concatenation: 1) it is playable; 2) it might be similar to the mp4 file (before it is packaged/segmented).

Answer (score 2):

Under Windows cmd shell you can use the copy command for file concatenation in the following way:

```
copy init.mp4 +segment*.m4s source.mp4
```

"help copy" does provide you all options

Comment: Did not work for me like that, I had to enable binary mode for copy: `copy /B ...`

Answer (score 0):

I use a less technical way which rename both audio and video segment to .mp4 and .ogg in Command Prompt and then join'em in a video editing software than export as .mp4 format. Although this way is less technical but it's easy for newbies in Information Technology.