# Compile init.mp4 and audio.mp4 that has segment timeline

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, widevine, mpd

I am trying to complie init.mp4 and its audio file 
using copy /b init.mp4 + audio.mp4  complie.mp4

It is compiling but, its not able to play on vlc and on ffmpeg play.

When I checked the mpd file, I see for audio  it has

```
            <SegmentTemplate timescale="48000" media="57_audio_1_17_$Number$.mp4?m=1532401844" initialization="57_audio_1_17_init.mp4?m=1532401844" startNumber="6815976">
                <SegmentTimeline>
                    <S t="1521333224447" d="479232" r="1"/>
                    <S t="1521334182911" d="483328"/>
                    <S t="1521334666239" d="479232" r="3"/>
                    <S t="1521336583167" d="483328"/>
                    <S t="1521337066495" d="479232" r="3"/>
                    <S t="1521338983423" d="483328"/>
                    <S t="1521339466751" d="479232" r="4"/>
                    <S t="1521341862911" d="483328"/>
                    <S t="1521342346239" d="479232" r="3"/>
                    <S t="1521344263167" d="483328"/>
                    <S t="1521344746495" d="479232" r="3"/>
                    <S t="1521346663423" d="483328"/>
                    <S t="1521347146751" d="479232" r="4"/>
                    <S t="1521349542911" d="483328"/>
                    <S t="1521350026239" d="479232" r="3"/>
                    <S t="1521351943167" d="483328"/>
                    <S t="1521352426495" d="479232" r="3"/>
                    <S t="1521354343423" d="483328"/>
                    <S t="1521354826751" d="479232" r="4"/>
                    <S t="1521357222911" d="483328"/>
                    <S t="1521357706239" d="479232" r="3"/>
                    <S t="1521359623167" d="483328"/>
                    <S t="1521360106495" d="479232" r="3"/>
                    <S t="1521362023423" d="483328"/>
                    <S t="1521362506751" d="479232" r="4"/>
                    <S t="1521364902911" d="483328"/>
                    <S t="1521365386239" d="479232" r="3"/>
                    <S t="1521367303167" d="483328"/>
                    <S t="1521367786495" d="479232" r="3"/>
                    <S t="1521369703423" d="483328"/>
                    <S t="1521370186751" d="479232" r="4"/>
                    <S t="1521372582911" d="483328"/>
                    <S t="1521373066239" d="479232" r="3"/>
                    <S t="1521374983167" d="483328"/>
                    <S t="1521375466495" d="479232" r="3"/>
                    <S t="1521377383423" d="483328"/>
                </SegmentTimeline>
            </SegmentTemplate>
        </Representation>
```

Can somebody explain  what it is ? And those t,r,d values are.
How do I add these audio segments to complie.mp4  and make it play ?

Comment: By complie you mean concatenate the files init.mp4 and audio.mp4 into a file called compile.mp4? The DASH specification usually cost money to get but a good source is usually the ffmpeg source code https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/dashdec.c#L40

Comment: This post explains how to convert the segments into an .mp4 file. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23485759/combine-mpeg-dash-segments-ex-init-mp4-segments-m4s-back-to-a-full-source-m/27017348

Comment: As you added the `widevine` tag, does that mean that the stream is DRM-protected? That would be the next problem after downloading and concatenating the files. You'd need to decrypt before playback.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to download the init.mp4 and then based on the SegmentTimeline download the segments.

For a `<SegmentTemplate>`, it’s common to use the `<SegmentTimeline>` tag to indicate how long each segment is and which segments repeat. A timescale (units to represent one second) is often included as part of the attributes of `<SegmentTemplate>` so that we can calculate the time of the segment based on this unit. In the example below, the `<S>` tag signifies a segment tag, the `d` attribute specifies how long the segment is and the `r` attribute specifies how many segments of the same duration repeat so that `$Time$` can be calculated properly for downloading the media segment as specified in the `media` attribute.

```
<SegmentTemplate>
  timescale="48000"
  initialization="$RepresentationID$-init.dash"
  media="$RepresentationID$-$Time$.dash"
    startNumber="1">
    <SegmentTimeline>
      <S t="0" d="96256" r="2" />
      <S d="95232" />
      <S d="96256" r="2" />
      <S d="95232" />
      <S d="96256" r="2" />
   </SegmentTimeline>
</SegmentTemplate>
```

The following is an example of a segment template from a representation. It uses the $Time$ variable.

```
<SegmentTemplate timescale="30000" media="155_video_1_2_$Time$.mp4?m=1545421124" initialization="155_video_1_2_init.mp4?m=1545421124" startNumber="710">
  <SegmentTimeline>
       <S t="255197799" d="360360" r="8"/>
       <S t="258441039" d="334334"/>
  </SegmentTimeline>
</SegmentTemplate>
```

The request URL for the first segment is **155_video_1_2_*255197799*.mp4**. With a 360360 duration, the next segment request is **155_video_1_2_*255558159*.mp4**, and so on through the ninth segment.

The final segment request is **155_video_1_2_*258441039*.mp4**.

If the segment template uses $Number$ instead of $Time$ then you download the files at the start number then repeat how ever many times indicated by r.

```
<AdaptationSet
            bitstreamSwitching="false"
            contentType="video"
            id="1"
            mimeType="video/mp4"
            segmentAlignment="true">
            <SegmentTemplate
                initialization="$RepresentationID$/init.mp4"
                media="$RepresentationID$/$Number$.m4f"
                startNumber="218646"
                timescale="90000">
                <SegmentTimeline>
                    <S
                        d="540540"
                        r="28"/>
                </SegmentTimeline>
            </SegmentTemplate>
            <Representation
                bandwidth="1199626"
                codecs="avc1.4D001E"
                frameRate="90000/3003"
                height="480"
                id="5501_video_seg_auto_video_32"
                width="528"/>
        </AdaptationSet>
```

The first file will be the start number and then repeat the segments 28 times. So start + 28 is 29 files plus init.mp4.

```
218646.m4f
218647.m4f
218648.m4f
218649.m4f
218650.m4f
218651.m4f
218652.m4f
218653.m4f
218654.m4f
218655.m4f
218656.m4f
218657.m4f
218658.m4f
218659.m4f
218660.m4f
218661.m4f
218662.m4f
218663.m4f
218664.m4f
218665.m4f
218666.m4f
218667.m4f
218668.m4f
218669.m4f
218670.m4f
218671.m4f
218672.m4f
218673.m4f
218674.m4f
init.mp4
```

Then you can convert the segments into an .mp4 file.

```
cat init.mp4 > source.mp4
cat segment-1.m4f >> source.mp4
cat segment-2.m4f >> source.mp4
...
```

References:

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/mpl/streaming_protocols

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediapackage/latest/ug/segtemp-format.html

[Combine MPEG-DASH segments (ex, init.mp4 + segments.m4s) back to a full source.mp4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23485759/combine-mpeg-dash-segments-ex-init-mp4-segments-m4s-back-to-a-full-source-m/27017348)

Comment: The problem is, in the MPD file, there is no $Time$ variable. Instead, it has $Number$.
I tried putting, 
57_audio_1_17_$Number$.mp4?m=1532401844
57_audio_1_17_1521333224447.mp4?m=1532401844

but, it is not working for me.

in the SegmentTemplate, there is something called startNumber="6815976"
I am able to download a mp4 file using this start number
57_audio_1_17_6815976.mp4?m=1532401844 like this.

But the audio is not completed, it is giving error.
can you check my edited post again to see the mpd file ?